# Better modifying the render or moving the camera?

Tags: opengl, camera, translation, scaling, jogl

Since I gogled for it without finding anything interesting, I would like to ask you for some suggestions regarding if it is better to scale/translate the render itself keeping the camera position fixed or maybe moving closer/further or rotate the camera keeping the render position fixed?

I need a zooming out/in, rotation in all the 3 axes and also this kind of rotation

http://www.reknow.de/downloads/opengl/video.mp4

that is, if I first translate my render and then I apply a rotation, this rotation should consider the center always the windows center, and not the translated one

Comment: A camera is a slightly higher-level concept than what OpenGL deals with.  In OpenGL, there is really just a transformation from the object coordinates directly to your view, and you can think of everything inbetween however you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need a zooming out/in, rotation in all the 3 axes and also this kind of rotation

What you mean is probably not "zooming" but "panning". And in OpenGL you place the "camera" by moving the scene around, because there is no camera.

Zooming is a change in the focal length, and would be implemented by changeing the FOV of the perspective.

Comment: Ok, thanks.

However how can I achieve such a movement?

http://www.reknow.de/downloads/opengl/video.mp4

Because right now, my rotation point lies always at the center of my rendered model